# Send a message to an updated number in Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe, sendmessage

I have a `SendSMS()` function in `customer.php` file, and I am updating the `MobileTelephone` field in the database. When the mobile number is updated a message should go to the new number. In my case, database updates and message goes to the previous number. I want to make them go to the new number. Any suggestions? 
Below is my function:

Below function is in MyAccountPage.php

```
function changeMyContactDetails($data,$form){

    $member = Customer::CurrentUser();
    //debug::show($member);
    if($member){

                if($data['MobileTelephone']!=$member-> MobileTelephone){
                //sleep(10);
                $verified = array(
                                'IsMobileVerified' => 'N',
                                //'MobileVeryDate' => date(MYSQL_DATETIME, strtotime(SS_Datetime::now()))
                            );
                            //sleep(10);
                            $member->update($verified);
                            $member->write();


                                //sleep(10);
                            $member = Customer::CurrentUser();
                            $member->SendSMS();


                }


        $form->saveInto($member);
        $member->write();

    }
    return $this->redirectBack();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have not altered member before sending the message.
use `Form::saveInto` first, not after sending.

This could also be done directly from member, in `onAfterWrite()`, using `$this->isChanged('MobileTelephone')`.
That way it is centralised so it doesn't matter which form/process updates the number.
It is best to achieve this through an Extension: http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/model/extending_dataobjects/

Comment: @user3358839 mark the answer as the right one if it worked for you.